# WTF: PARAMETRIC dynamic form?

Tags: python, forms, dynamic, flask, wtforms

I know how to create ?Dynamic Form? from the docs :

```
http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/1.0.2/specific_problems.html#dynamic-form-composition
```

What I need is to be able to create Dynamic Parametric form, what do I mean ?
Here is the scenario, I have two db tables :

```
table Category and table SubCategory.
every Category may have different number of SubCategories
```

Based on category_id I have to extract all the subcategories (where every item is 1 line of the generated form). The subcategory can not be edited they are only for display and the sub_category_id has to be part of the form (i.e would be submitted as data).

FORM :

```
Category name
   SubCategory1   : [ .... ]   <== text field for quantity
   SubCategory2   : [ .... ]   <== text field for quantity
   SubCategory3   : [ .... ] 
   .......
   SubCategoryN   : [ .... ]
```

Again category_id is parameter on which the form creation is decided i.e. category_id is the parameter on which I do a db query, extract all subcategories and build a FORM-field for every one of them.
One item would look something like (pseudo code) :

```
{{subat.name}} <input id={{subcat.id}}> quantity </input>
```

How do I do that ?

---

I think I have some solution using BaseForm. Will post it when I feel it works. But don't let you stop you to print other solutions.

---

Here is simplified version. Seems to works so far. (haven't tested the form submission yet).

```
def build_form(self, id):
    items = db.session.query(Blah).filter_by(id=id)
    fields = {}
    data = {}
    for it in items :
        field = StringField(render_kw={ 'xname' : it.name })
        fields[name] = field
        data[name] = ""
    form = BaseForm(fields)
    form.process(obj=data)
    return form
```

The important thing is that you have to call .process() with epmty data items, otherwise all hell break loose. :), took me awhile to figure that out.

hth.. still if you have better solution do not hesitate to post.

Comment: Did you *try* [this](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/1.0.2/specific_problems.html#dynamic-form-composition) ?

Comment: yes, I mentioned it at the beginning.

Comment: So, what went wrong with that?..It would be helpful to post why your tried.